# hidden symbol `stat' in libc_nonshared.a(stat.oS) is referenced by DSO

Tags: c, gcc, ld, gcc-warning

I'm trying to use methods contained in a shared library (`libscplugin.so`).

I have satisfied all of the libraries requirements:

- `libc.so` with a symlink to `libc.so.6`
- `libz.so` with a symlink to `libz.so.1.2.8`
- `libstdc++.so` with a symlink to `libstdc++.so.6.0.20`

Upon compilation I get the following error message:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ -lscplugin
/usr/bin/ld: test: hidden symbol `stat' in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc_nonshared.a(stat.oS) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The only reference I could find to `libc_nonshared.a` is in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so`:

```
$ cat libc.so
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 ) )
```

In `test.c` I'm attempting to use two functions of the shared library (totally unrelated to `stat`). What can I do to get this to compile ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

> I have satisfied all of the libraries requirements:
>
> - `libc.so` with a symlink to `libc.so.6`

That is not a valid setup for glibc. `libc.so` is supposed to be a text file (linker script) as you saw at the end of your answer. You're doing something weird and unnecessary if you're making symlinks to shared libraries like this yourself. Use the `libc.so` that's provided (and you need to do this when building your other shared libraries -- your problem right now is that they were mis-linked) and everything will work fine.

Comment: Removing the symlink results in the following output:

   "/usr/bin/ld: warning: libc.so, needed by /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf//libscplugin.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)"

Even though `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so` exists

Comment: Can you clarify what your setup is? Are you cross compiling or working with your host system's native compiler? What distro are you using?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 14.10 (Linux feelinsonice-hrd 3.2.34-30 #17 SMP Mon Apr 13 15:53:45 UTC 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux), not cross compiling. The shared library I'm using is for the `armeabi-v7a` platform.

Comment: Where does `libscplugin.so` come from? It sounds like it was improperly linked.

Comment: It's extracted from an Android app

Comment: That's your problem then. This library is linked against Bionic, not glibc. It might be possible to use it via `libhybris`.