# Code coverage (gcov) failing when C Functions used in a C++ app

Tags: c++, linker-errors, gcov

I have a C++ app where I use some C functions. I have declared those C functions inside extern "C" {}; And it is compiling and working just fine.
I am using 'gcc' for compiling the C code, and using 'g++' for linking that object with C++ object.

GCOV fails by throwing me the following error:

```
hidden symbol `__gcov_init' in /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcov.a(_gcov.o) is referenced by DSO
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea as this is new to me combining C and C++ code. Any one have idea why "gcov" failing with linking stage. If I disable those "C" functions in my app then it "gcov" is not giving me that error.

C Functions I am using just initialising a struct which has function pointers in it with some functions.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143114/hidden-symbol-stat-in-libc-nonshared-astat-os-is-referenced-by-dso

Comment: `extern "C"` is not C but C++. It does not make your code magically C. It still is C++ code.

Comment: or possibly this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900744/gcov-final-link-failed?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding "-lgcov" flag while linking, but I don't know why it did not work even though "--coverage" flag should do the linking for this. Only have this problem when linking C object file with C++ object.

Here is the link for the answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/567296/7152961)